# AngularfireAuth for Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire2

Anyone know the new code for the Angularfire - Angular 4 `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method?

```
loginWithEmail(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password));
}
```

This returns error:

```
Type 'firebase.Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<any>'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can avoid the error by importing `firebase` and change `Promise<any>` to `firebase.Promise<any>`.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

loginWithEmail(email: string, password: string): firebase.Promise<any> {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

/**
   * @Description: Global function
   * @param gpAfAuth
   * @Author: gpCoders
   */
    constructor(private gpAfAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

  /**
   * @Description: Authorize user
   * @Author: gpCoders
   */
    gpAuthorize(gpEmail: string, gpPassword: string) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.gpAfAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(gpEmail, gpPassword)
          .then(userData => resolve(userData),
          err => reject(err));
      });
    }
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanations. Raw code is rarely really helpful.